# Split function throws error

Tags: c++, string, split

I'm trying to make a function to split a string, "Split At Spaces", into a vector which would contain "Split" "At" "Spaces".  So far, this is the code I've got.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string * s, char * tosplit) 
{
    size_t i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    size_t contain;
    std::vector<std::string> split;

    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
    std::cout << *s << std::endl;
    std::cout << *tosplit << std::endl;

    while((contain = s->find(*tosplit,i)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        count++;
        i = contain + 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Contains " << count << std::endl;

    if (count == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Equals 0" << std::endl;
        split = std::vector<std::string>(1);
        split.at(0) = s->c_str();
        return split;
    }

    split = std::vector<std::string>(count + 1);
    split.begin();

    int lasti;
    i = s->find_first_of(*tosplit);
    split.at(0) = s->substr(0, i);
    lasti = i;
    int runs = 1;

    while (runs <= count) 
    {
        i = s->find(*tosplit, lasti + 1);
        std::cout << i << " " << lasti << std::endl;
        split.at(runs) = s->substr(lasti, --i);
        runs++;
        lasti = i;
    }

    split.at(runs) = s->substr(lasti, s->size());

    std::cout << "done, result is" << std::endl;
    i = 0;
    while (i < split.capacity()) 
    {
        std::cout << split.at(i) << std::endl;
        i++;
    }

    return split;
}
```

It throws an out_of_range exception.  Any help you can give would be appreciated.  This is like my first part using pointers in a function so I'm kinda guessing here.
Thanks!

Please don't suggest using x or y method, **I'd like to write my own** as I'm doing it for the experience.

Comment: Why are you using pointers with `std::string`?

Comment: You don't need to pass char as a pointer either.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line throw the exception?

Comment: What are values for the parameters when the exception is thrown?

Comment: `std::vector::capacity` does not return the **size** of the vector.

Comment: Please look up `std::string` to find out how to use the `begin` method.  In your post, you might as well remove it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Technically it's a vector, and I made that mistake as well, but all that needs to change is the type and it's still a valid concern.

Comment: @chris: Yes, I reviewed the post and `split` is a vector not a string.  In either case, I don't think it does what the OP wants.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Definitely not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Single Delimiter:**

You wrote much too much code to do this. You can do it in a few lines. You are getting *very* over complicated. And there's no reason to really do anything with pointers for this.

```
vector<string> Split(string s, char delim)
{
    vector<string> strings;
    for(istringstream ss(s); getline(ss, s, delim); strings.push_back(move(s)));
    return strings;
}
```

**Multiple Delimiters:**

A solution for using multiple delimiters is more complicated. You can no longer leverage off of `getline`, which means you're basically writing part of `getline`'s functionality yourself. But still, it can be quite short.

```
vector<string> Split(const string& s, const char* delims)
{
    vector<string> strings;

    for(string::size_type start = 0, end; end != string::npos && start < s.size(); start = end+1)
    {
        end = s.find_first_of(delims, start);
        strings.push_back(s.substr(start, end-start));
    }

    return strings;
}
```

This will add blank strings when delimiters are next to each-other. If that's not the desired behavior for adjacent delimiters, this can be easily avoided by guarding the `push_back` with `if(start != end)`.

**Conclusion:**

When you are starting to write a low level algorithm like this, pseudo code it out in broad terms and then before writing any code check what the C++ standard library can provide to cut out parts or all of your work. You'll end up with smaller, less error prone, and more understandable code. No one wants to see a hand rolled implementation for `find_first_of`, for example. It's much more clear to read the words `find_first_of`. It's clear what that function is going to do, and that it's bug free (hopefully).

Comment: Jesus I completely missed that.  Is there any way to split on two delims? (e.x. + and a space

Comment: @Tips48 I edited my answer to include a solution for multiple delims

Comment: Using your code, I get this error: Error 7 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > __cdecl split(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,char)" I left off the rest of the error but if it's important let me know.  Also, any chance you could explain what the const and & are used for in the string and char variable? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually easy to do with e.g. [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), together with some help from the [standard iterator library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

For those that want to see working code, it can be found [here](http://ideone.com/5WalM7).

For the code in the link, the *whole program* is 18 lines, of which the actual splitting is three lines but that's because I split it to make it more readable (it's actually a single function call).

---

For a more general solution, and if C++11 [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) are available (or [Boost regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html), or some other regular expression library is available) that could be used to.

Comment: "Please don't suggest using x or y method, I'd like to write my own as I'm doing it for the experience."

Comment: I was going to post the faq entry until I saw the last line of the post. Still, they can be used for inspiration.

Comment: @Rapptz Oops, didn't see that first, updated my answer to remove code.

Comment: I don't think putting a spoiler on a link is really necessary ;)

Comment: @chris Probably not, but I've never used spoiler before. :)

Comment: Can't split on arbitrary characters anyway.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Could've used std::copy to cout as well :) But, this gets more hard to split on a particular character

Answer (score 1):

Here are some issues I have found:

1. Dereferencing `s` before checking for NULL pointer.
2. Dereferencing `tosplit` before checking for NULL.
3. Instead of counting the number of strings and then splitting the
   string (requiring 2 searches), count as you search.
4. The position `i = contain + 1` may be out of range when you pass it
   to the expression in the `while` loop.
5. Try using the method `std::vector::push_back` rather than assigning
   at a specific, maybe unallocated, position.
6. The statement `return split` returns a copy of an array of strings. 
   Do you really want to return a large data structure?
7. The statement `split.begin()` returns an iterator to the beginning
   of the vector; which you don't use.
8. Use `split.size()` not `split.capacity`.  They are two different
   concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to pre-allocate the space for your vector, just use push_back to append the parts as you find them.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I can't help thinking that your function is overly complicated. If you want to code the logic yourself for learning rather than using some pre-packed functionality, that's fine, but this doesn't mean you should not keep your logic **simple**.

I believe your algorithm should look more like this one:

```
// Note that the delimiter can be a string as well, not just a char
vector<string> split(string const& s, string const& delimiter)
{
    vector<string> result;

    string::size_type startPos = 0;
    string::size_typepos = s.find(delimiter);
    while (pos != string::npos)
    {
        // Extract token and save it...
        string token = s.substr(startPos, pos - startPos);
        result.push_back(token);

        // Step to next token...
        startPos = pos + 1;
        pos = s.find(delimiter, pos + 1);
    }

    // Parse last token (in case the string is not terminated
    // by the delimiter).
    if (startPos < s.length())
    {
        string lastToken = s.substr(startPos);
        result.push_back(lastToken);
    }

    return result;
}
```